# Banning specific web users

Tags: flash, cookies, ip-address, identity

I came across a situation recently.

As any self respecting programmer would, when I got banned from a website, I tried to find a way round it, while still using the same computer. But I wasn't successful. I've subsequently had the ban lifted, but the question remains:

How did it remember my identity, even though I cleared cookies and changed IP? It was a flash app, but I didn't think flash could store its own data of any kind, so I'm puzzled! While on the subject, could a java applet be used to store data?

So, Besides cookies/IP address, how might a website remember a user?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I didn't think flash could store its own data of any kind" - and you were wrong. There is something called Flash Cookies (oficially named "Local Shared Objects", they are pretty much what it says on the tin: small persistent pieces of data accessible to Flash, separate from HTTP cookies). See e.g. this: http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/04/flash-cookies-explained/

It is possible to delete these through a Flash control panel; and as @Samuel Neff notes, some browsers can now remove them together with HTTP cookies.

See also a combined-approach mutant form, [the evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/); plus there is at least a theoretical possibility that your browser's header data, although anonymous separately, are unique enough to identify you when analyzed together - see https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: Technically they're called "Local Shared Objects" in Flash speak.  More recently browsers are starting to clear these out when the browser's own cookies are cleared, and Adobe is making it easier for browsers to do this automatically.